# pass value from html form to python script

Tags: python

`python.py`

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("login")
def home():
    return render_template('login.html',name='login')
@app.route("/")
def calculation():
    return render_template('function.html')
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

function.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h3>Simple Calculator</h3>
<br/>
<style>
#calc{width:300px;height:250px;}
#btn{width:100%;height:40px;font-size:20px;}
</style>
<form Name="calc">
<table id="calc" border=2>
<tr>
<td colspan=5><input id="btn" name="display" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" type="text"></td>
<td style="display:none"><input name="M" type="number"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td><input id="btn" type=button value="0" OnClick="calc.display.value+='0'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="1" OnClick="calc.display.value+='1'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="2" OnClick="calc.display.value+='2'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="+" OnClick="calc.display.value+='+'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td><input id="btn" type=button value="3" OnClick="calc.display.value+='3'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="4" OnClick="calc.display.value+='4'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="5" OnClick="calc.display.value+='5'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="-" OnClick="calc.display.value+='-'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td><input id="btn" type=button value="6" OnClick="calc.display.value+='6'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="7" OnClick="calc.display.value+='7'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="8" OnClick="calc.display.value+='8'"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="x" OnClick="calc.display.value+='*'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td><input id="btn" type=button value="9" OnClick="calc.display.value+='9'"></td>
    </td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="=" OnClick="calc.display.value=eval(calc.display.value)"></td>
<td><input id="btn" type=button value="/" OnClick="calc.display.value+='/'"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`login.html`

```
     <html>
     <head><title>welcome</title></head>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="container">
        <label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <link rel="next" href="function.html">
      </div>
      </form>
     </html>
```

I have created this python file and I have created two html files. I dont know how to validate from python to html file
create the following sample using flask framework

1. create a home page in that place your name and add the two buttons like calculator and      form
2. while clicking the calculator button the page have to redirect the another page in that page all calculator function have to present like add, sub, multiplication and division
3. while clicking the form button the page have to redirect the another page in that create the two textfields like username , password and button like submit when the submit button is clicked the typed username and password have to display in the bottom of the webpage.

This is my task through that I have to written the code above but I can't render the html file to python.

Comment: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments

Answer (score 0):

1) Create another html page(index.html), which contains two hyperlinks for form and calculator.

2) Make index.html as your root(/) in python file.

3) Now create another two routes namely 'forms' and 'calculator' which will render the pages 'login.html' and 'function.html' respectively.

4) Create another route 'submit' which will get data from your form to python script.

Then your python route should look something like this,

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/calculator")
def calculation():
    return render_template('function.html')

@app.route("/form")
def form():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route("/submit", methods = ['POST'])
def submit():
    return 'username : '+request.form['uname']+'password : 'request.form['work-flow-id']
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments